# Bootstrap datepicker restriction

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using Bootstrap datepicker in a form. i want it to have only the present date and every date after the present date. This is why i used the following function :

```
$('#datedepart').datepicker({
    onRender: function(date) {
    return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
  }
```

with this datepicker

```
        <div class="form-group col-lg-2 col-md-2">
            <label class="funzies" for="pweazed">Le:</label>
            <input type="text" data-role="date" name="date"  id ="datedepart"  class="datepicker form-control col-lg-5" value=""  required >
        </div>
```

And when i validate my form with the datepicker restriction i got this error

```
{"success":false,"data":[],"message":"Undefined index: data","errors":null,"tid":null,"trace":null,"count":null,"totalCount":null,"metaData":[]}
```

The fact is that i got this error only when i'm using this restriction. The restriction itself is working on the datepicker, i can pick't pick past dates, but it makes my form crash somehow, only by adding these few lines...

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `startDate` option of bootstrap datepicker.

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#startdate

Comment: Looks like this ain't working, he doesn't know startDate

Comment: he simple doesn't recognize startDate, he thinks it's a variable not a parameter, and the error after the validation remains the same. I noticed something also, when i choose a date with the datepicker using the restriction, a small white thing pops on the left of my screen, like an empty datepicker. i don't get what it is i'm really lost right now

Comment: can you share your page URL?

Comment: i wish i could but it's on a private server inside of a company so i can't :(